# How to add an attribute to grep () Output

Tags: r

What I'm trying to do is following: 
use a `grep()` function to search for a pattern (a list of numbers, which I called "toMatch") in a `data.frame` ("News"). So, what I want it to do is search for those numbers in the news and return the matches (in the form "number", "corresponding news"). Unfortunately, I could so far only get a list of the corresponding news as a result. Any idea how I can add an attribute with the corresponding number from the match to the output? (in a way create a key-value pairs as an output)

Here a simple short example of my code:

```
News <- c ("AT000000STR2 is schwierig", "AT", "ATI", "AT000000STR1")
toMatch <- c("AT000000STR1","AT000000STR2","DE000000STR1","DE000000STR2")
matches <- unique (grep(paste(toMatch,collapse="|"),News, value=TRUE))
matches
```

And here the result:

```
> matches
[1] "AT000000STR2 is schwierig" "AT000000STR1" `
```

What I would like to have is a list or better yet Excel file, looking like this:

```
 AT000000STR2 "AT000000STR2 is schwierig" 
 AT000000STR1 "AT000000STR1"
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you expect multiple unique matches per element of 'toMatch'? What should the output be then? And what have you tried yourself in this?

Comment: Not in this sample but for my use case there probably will be. I'm guessing there will be numbers that correspond with 2 or more news. However, I do believe I handle this already by the unique funktion? Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I meant what if for instance there is a "AT000000STR1B" and a "AT000000STR1C" in your data. They are not unique, and will both match "AT000000STR1".

Comment: Good point... I think an exact match () would be an option in this case. Let me try putting this in code and get back to you

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might be of help:

```
#name toMatch with its names
names(toMatch) <- toMatch

#create a list with the format you request
myl <-
lapply(toMatch, function(x) {
  grep(x, News, value=TRUE)
  })
#or in a more compact way as @BenBolker says in the comments below
#myl <- lapply(toMatch, grep, x=News, value=TRUE)

#remove the unmatched
myl[lapply(myl,length)>0]
```

Output:

```
$AT000000STR1
[1] "AT000000STR1"

$AT000000STR2
[1] "AT000000STR2 is schwierig"
```

Comment: I think `myl <- lapply(toMatch, grep, x=News, value=TRUE)` would also work (same thing but slightly more compact)

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker . You are right it is more compact. I ve gotten into the habit of using anonymous functions each time :). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your current approach returns the unique matches, but then you have no way of linking them to the relevant 'toMatch'.

This might be a start for you: using lapply we create a list of matches for all elements of toMatch, and then bind those together with toMatch.

```
matched  <- lapply(toMatch, function(x){grep(x,News,value=T)})
#turn unfound matches to missings. You can remove these, but I don't like
#generating implicit missings
matched[sapply(matched,length)==0]<-NA

res <- cbind(toMatch,matched)
res
     toMatch        matched                    
[1,] "AT000000STR1" "AT000000STR1"             
[2,] "AT000000STR2" "AT000000STR2 is schwierig"
[3,] "DE000000STR1" NA                         
[4,] "DE000000STR2" NA
```

writing to csv is then trivial:

```
write.csv(res,"yourfile.csv")
```